# Temporarily Override Login Message from Specific Redirected Route with Flask-Login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a Flask app and am using Flask-Login to manage user authentication. The main route ('/') requires login, however I would not like it to flash the error message defined for this specific route. I would like it to behave as it should flashing the error messages for other routes but not this one. Here is a snippet from my **init**.py

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view =  'login'
login_manager.login_message = 'You Must Login to Access This Page!'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'error'
```

The following is from my views.py

```
@app.route('/')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = Employee.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and user.is_valid_pass(form.password.data):
            remember = form.remember.data == 'y'
            login_user(user, remember=remember)
            next = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next or url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            flash(u'Incorrect Username or Password!', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

As you can see I have the main route password protected, and because of the login_manager settings it is flashing the message "You Must Login to Access This Page!" and of course I'm displaying those errors on the login template. However, how can I ensure that this functions accordingly for every route EXCEPT the main ('/') route? I've been through the documentation but I see nothing that would indicate it could be done.

Can I simply overwrite the login_manager.login_message with None in that specific route? If so, how would the login manager be appropriately called, overwritten, and then changed back?

Comment: On authentication failure, instead of redirecting to login page, render login template, that way you will save 1 redirection and form values will be intact.
Also, you should not redirect to `next` variable without checking if it's safe or not. To check if next is safe url or not use [this](https://github.com/fengsp/flask-snippets/blob/master/security/redirect_back.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was simply passing the value of the GET variable "next" that Flask-Login uses in these cases to the template from the view. Then choosing not to display flashes in the case where it matches the route I don't want to display from.

In the view:

```
next = request.args.get('next')
render_template('dashboard.html' form=form, next=next)
```

In the template:

```
{% if next != '/' %}
  //Loop Displaying Flash Errors
{% endif %}
```

There may be an easier way to discard flashes in the view and you still want to make sure you have something doing get_flashed_messages() otherwise they'll just pile up at some point when you actually do display flash.